# How to mitigate XSRF for ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink requests?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, csrf

I have many `Ajax.ActionLink`'s on my ASP.NET MVC (v1) page that perform destructive operations.  This is "legal" because I set HttpMethod to `DELETE` in this case so it's not a destructive `GET`.

My question though is how to mitigate XSRF attacks on this operation so that other sites cannot craft this same Ajax `DELETE` request to delete user data from another site.  This ActionLink does appear within a form that includes `<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>` but since ActionLinks don't post the form, the anti-forgery token doesn't go to the controller, so it can't validate it.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent against Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks you must block requests that originate from another site.  In asp.net you can do this by checking to see if Request.UrlReferrer isn't from your host name.  If the ajax request originated from a different server, then you should ignore the ajax request.   If the referrer is null,  then you should also ignore the request.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the UrlReferrer comes from an HTTP header that is often stripped by proxies or firewalls (for privacy reasons), so denying ajax requests based on that header causes the web site to misbehave for legitimate requests.
I'm looking for how to best implement the standard approach of matching a secret on the client (usually a hidden field in the form) and a secret on the server to authorize the POST.

Comment: Furthermore, the `Referer` header can easily be spoofed.

Comment: @Paul d'Aoust It is impossible to spoof the `Referer` header in a CSRF attack, which is the topic of conversation here.

Comment: oh, of course, because it's all about commandeering someone _else_ into doing something for you, and you can't tell them to spoof any headers. Thanks for the reminder; so many moving parts in Internet security!

Comment: @Paul d'Aoust :)  I remember coming to the same realization.

Answer (score 0):

This link covers one solution http://tpeczek.com/2010/05/using-antiforgerytoken-with-other-verbs.html

However the most ideal solution is that when you use the actionlink it adds the Anti Forgery token into the query string so I'm going to try writing my own ActionLink extension method that appends that on.

Finally I'm going to write an attribute that inherits from the ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute and that accepts forgery tokens in both the Request.Form and Request.QueryString